# Get group description in Workplace

Tags: facebook-workplace

I'm trying to get the description of a Workplace Group, but with no luck.
if I try

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}?fields=description&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&appsecret_proof={APP_SECRET_PROOF}&appsecret_time={APP_SECRET_TIME}
```

all I get back is the group ID. Without filters I can get id, name, privacy.
Could it be a permission issue? I have the `read group content` permission, and in fact I can access *some* data, but if I try fields like `owner` or `cover` they are just ignored, and if I try to query edges like `members` or `admins` it just return an empty array... Although, if I query `feed` I get the posts back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the conundrum on my own: if the group has no description then the field is ignored in the final result, even if you explicitly query it.
Maybe a `"description": null` or `"description": ""` would have been more clear, but it's not my API...